# Do na-adjectives have an attributive negative form?

Tags: negation, na-adjectives, attributive

Assuming present tense, we can use i-adjectives in an attributive context both in the affirmative form:

> 高い　椅子　が　あります　- there's an expensive chair

And in the negative form:

> 高くない　椅子　が　あります　- there's an inexpensive chair

---

I know we can use na-adjectives similarly in the affirmative form:

> 綺麗な　人　が　います　- there's a pretty person

But for the life of me I can't find any info on whether using na-adjectives in the negative form is allowed in an attributive context (i.e. modifying a noun rather than as a predicative with a copula). So is the following grammatical?

> 綺麗じゃない　人　が　います　- there's a non-pretty person

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your guessed-at negative attributive is perfectly correct.  The only caveat I'd add is that じゃ is a somewhat-informal contraction for では, and thus you should probably use the full では form in any formal spoken or written context.

> 綺麗[じゃ]{●}ない　人　が　います
>             ↓
>   綺麗[で]{●}[は]{●}ない　人　が　います

Happy studying!

Answer (score 1):

Although the name might scare people away, [Japanesewithanime](https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2018/11/na-adjectives.html?m=1#attributive-form) actually has a really in-depth post that covers this topic. I'll just quote the relevant part discussing why your guess was right, but there's a ton more information, so you might want to read through it.

> The na of na-adjectives is actually a copula. The prenominal copula, or attributive copula.
>
> Basically, da だ is the copula you use in an independent clause, while na な is the copula you use in an attributive clause, also called adjectival clause. A clause that describes nouns.

But there isn't a negative form of な, so you have to go back to だ.

> The negative form of na-adjectives is literally just replacing the normal copula by a negative copula such as denai でない, dewanai ではない or its contraction, janai じゃない.

He includes a link talking about the difference in usage between [ではない and でない](https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1363483578)

Comment: That's a really neat article! Thanks for the link!